# Angular - set placeholder in template by parameter

Tags: angularjs, templates, directive

I amb using the bootstrap-datepicker directive and I am trying to set a placeholder in the input that the directive creates:

The directive replaces the html code that calls it with a static template. Here is the directive:

```
dp.directive('ngDatepicker', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      ngOptions: '=',
      ngModel: '='
    },    
    template: '<div class="input-append date">\n  <input type="text" placeholder="{{myPlaceholder}}" ><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar">    </i></span>\n</div>',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.inputHasFocus = false;
      element.datepicker(scope.ngOptions).on('changeDate', function(e) {
        var defaultFormat, defaultLanguage, format, language;
        defaultFormat = $.fn.datepicker.defaults.format;
        format = scope.ngOptions.format || defaultFormat;
        defaultLanguage = $.fn.datepicker.defaults.language;
        language = scope.ngOptions.language || defaultLanguage;
        return scope.$apply(function() {
          return scope.ngModel = $.fn.datepicker.DPGlobal.formatDate(e.date, format, language);
        });
      });
      element.find('input').on('focus', function() {
        return scope.inputHasFocus = true;
      }).on('blur', function() {
        return scope.inputHasFocus = false;
      });
      return scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newValue) {
        if (!scope.inputHasFocus) {
          return element.datepicker('update', newValue);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is to set a custom text in the placeholder of the template that it creates, I pass that text to the directive using the options that is sent to the directive:

```
$scope.datepickerOptions = {format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', language: 'es', autoclose: true, weekStart: 1, placeholder: 'Birthdate'};
```

the output of the code above results in a input with its placeholder showing "{{myPlaceholder}}".

Using the compile function instead of the static template would be much easier to do what I am trying, but since the directive is already written and dont want to mess it up i would like to try it in the template html.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In place of this {{myPlaceholder}} use {{datepickerOptions.placeholder}} and see if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

`myPlaceholder` is undefined.  You pass the placeholder to the directive as a property of the `ngOptions` object.  Use this instead:

```
placeholder="{{ngOptions.placeholder}}"
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/WB80J7dHFq2ammmQybMu?p=preview